# How 'Desktop' Directory Works

Tags: filesystems, directory, desktop

The desktop seems to pretend to be a snapshot of a file explorer where you can access the contents of an actual directory.

I think it would be nice to be able to make it less static where the desktop behaves more like a complete file explorer (i.e. opening a folder on the desktop would remove all current shortcuts on the desktop and replace them with the shortcuts in that folder).

Truthfully, I'm just sick of file explorers, there must be a better way!

Direction to forum/chat room where things like this are discussed would be nice.

Thanks.

Comment: That is actually dependent on what Desktop Environment or Window Manager (or both...) that you are using...

Comment: In which desktop environment?  With which window manager?  On what distribution?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much every major desktop environment follows the behavior that started decades ago with some of the earliest graphical interfaces.  There are a couple of reasons why treating the desktop special like this is useful:

- It provides quick access that is always there.  You don't have to worry about navigating back to get to things.  Take a look at the application menu most desktops have by default for another example of this.
- It removes the need to store items as actual files (think for example of the Trash/Recycle Bin, this is actually a special link on almost all desktops that merges data from multiple sources).
- It actually makes the implementation a lot easier in many respects (drawing in the background is usually much more complicated than drawing in a window, so redrawing the desktop regularly (to handle changing of directories would be somewhat difficult to do efficiently).
- It matches up with the paradigm most people intuitively expect based on the name.  The act of opening a traditional file on a desk works pretty much the same as clicking a folder on a computer desktop, you end up with a view of that file/folder on top of whatever was already there, not in place of it.

There have been some systems that handled this differently though over the years, with AmigaOS (and by extension, AROS) being a good example.  On AmigaOS, the 'desktop' actually is a special file manager window that's been configured to open anything you click as a new window and always be at the bottom of the window stack.  That behavior has some issues (most notably that you can move the 'desktop' far enough off screen that you can't get it back any more without restarting the GUI), but has actually been copied in a slightly different form by some UNIX desktop environments (which often share code between their file manager and the actual desktop program).